# Block file system and internet access in a C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I know is not a very good practice and it is very dangerous to allow a user to run C# code from a website in my server but this is a very specific scenario that I need, I would like some security recommendations.

So the scenario is: an MVC5 application where the user will be able to write few lines of c# code and will be able to execute it.

How can I be sure that he doesn't run code that can affect/manipulate my server?

Thanks.

Comment: Obvious answer: it depends on the way you've choosen to run code written by user.

Comment: Since the question is very broad, this duplicate fits best. If you want to, please elaborate on the actual problem at hand and how you want this code to be ran. It might get your question reopened. Just ping me using @Patrick and I can reopen (just like others can).

Comment: This might be useful to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx